# Why does MusicProperties->Year always return the current year?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, c++-cx

I'm trying to get the music properties for each file in the music library by using the StorageFolder APIs.

After calling GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery::OrderByName) on my music library I'm iterating over the resulting IVectorView^ and calling StorageFile->Properties->GetMusicPropertiesAsync() for each file, which is inherently slow but I have to do it this way, since [QueryOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994634.aspx) are not supported on Windows Phone for some reason.

Anyway, after completing that task every property is correct except for MusicProperties->Year, which is 2014 for every single one of well over 900 music files on my phone. Here's a short code snippet:

```
create_task(lib->GetFilesAsync(Search::CommonFileQuery::OrderByName))
    .then([](IVectorView<StorageFile^>^ songFiles)
{
    auto taskPtr = std::make_shared<std::vector<task<Song>>>(songFiles->Size);

    for (size_t i = 0, len = songFiles->Size; i < len; ++i)
    {
        StorageFile^ song = songFiles->GetAt(i);
        (*taskPtr)[i] = create_task(song->Properties->GetMusicPropertiesAsync()).then([]
            (MusicProperties^ props) 
        {

            Song s;
            s.album = std::wstring(std::move(props->Album->Data()));
            s.artist = std::wstring(std::move(props->Artist->Data()));
            s.title = std::wstring(std::move(props->Title->Data()));
            s.track = props->TrackNumber;
            s.year = props->Year;

            return s;
        });
    }

    //further processing is done in a when_all function after the song tasks have completed
}
```

Song is just a plain struct to save my result temporarily and convert it to JSON later on, but that Year property is freaking me out. Has anybody else encountered that issue already and is there any other way to retrieve the proper release year from a music file?

Comment: Are you sure that the year is set properly on the files in question? I wonder if the ID3 tags are set properly but are not being translated to the file properties by the phone? Have you tried opening the phone in explorer by plugging it in to a PC and checking the Year of the files that way?

Comment: Hm, interesting. There is no year property if I open the properties dialog on the phone, but when I move the file to my PC it is there and it's set like it's supposed to be.

Maybe that information is saved by those referenced files in the hidden album folder, I should check that out.

Comment: I tried to get the year property from an album folder by making a deep query with CommonFolderQuery::GroupByAlbum, then calling GetMusicPropertiesAsync as I did above. Sadly, the result is 0, so that property is certainly not saved there.

Comment: I would look into an ID3 tag reader library to see if you can't find it that way. I know C# has `taglib#`.

Comment: Yeah, I'll try to do it that way. Thanks for the suggestion, I actually wanted to use taglib, but that'd need some porting work because WinRT does only work with StorageFile objects.
Might as well use the C# library if I'm too lazy to port it over.